# Is it possible to align content dynamically according to its length?

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I was making frontmatter for my thesis.

The title page contains something like:

```
Title:            some centered text
Instructors:           somebody
...:                     ...
```

So I placed them in a two-column tabular, with the first column left aligned and the second centered. But when the second column has a long text (long title or many instructors), it turns into:

```
Title:       some centered very very very
                    looooong text
Instructors:           somebody
...:                     ...
```

While I want it to be left aligned instead, something like this:

```
Title:       some centered very very very
             looooong text
Instructors:           somebody
...:                     ...
```

Comment: \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} when the default is p{<width>}, or vice verses.  Or did you put "loooooong text" in a separate row?

Comment: @JohnKormylo No. I just want it to be done automatically. One does not need to pay attention to the length of the content.

Comment: You can have automatic line breaking only if you specify a width.  If you don't want to specify a width, use \multicolumn{1}{l}{...} for every line of text.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I use a `p` column with width. The problem here is that I want the text centered if no more than one line, otherwise left aligned.

Comment: Ah, you want a single-line check.  That can be done.  I suppose you want me to create your MWE for you.  (sigh!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\SLcheck}[2]% #1 = width, #2 = text
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd0>#1\relax \parbox[t]{#1}{#2}%
  \else \usebox0
  \fi
 \egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
Title: & \SLcheck{4cm}{some justified very very very looooong text} \\
Instructors: & \SLcheck{4cm}{somebody}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

The next step is to create a new column type using the array package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{SLcheck}[1]% #1 = width
{\def\myarg{#1}% local definition
  \begin{lrbox}{0}}{\end{lrbox}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\myarg\relax \parbox[t]{\myarg}{\unhbox0}%
  \else \box0
  \fi
}

\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\SLcheck{#1}}c<{\endSLcheck}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lQ{4cm}}
Title: & some justified very very very looooong text \\
Instructors: & somebody
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! learned a lot from your demo.